# Join more table using with LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a problem joining 1 more table using with LINQ in C#. Now my query can join 1 table.My existing query is `TnWhatsapp` table join `Tenant` table Below is my coding:

```html
var query = _saasdbContext.TnWhatsapp.AsNoTracking();

if (isSAASAdmin == false)
    query = query.Where(x => x.TenantId == tenantID);

int totalCount = await query.CountAsync();
query = QueryableExtensions.QueryOrderBy(query, sortList);
List<TnWhatsappMessage> whatsappDedicatedListForTenant = new List<TnWhatsappMessage>();

if (take == 0)
    whatsappDedicatedListForTenant = await query.Skip(skip)
                                    .Join(_saasdbContext.Tenant.AsNoTracking(),
                                    tnWhatsapp => tnWhatsapp.TenantId,
                                    tenant => tenant.Id,
                                    //(tnWhatsapp, tenant) => new { tnWhatsapp, tenant })
                                    //.Join(_saasdbContext.TnBranch.AsNoTracking(),
                                    //branch => branch.Id,
                                    (tnWhatsapp, tenant) => new TnWhatsappMessage()
                                    {
                                        Id = tnWhatsapp.Id,
                                        TenantId = tnWhatsapp.TenantId,
                                        BranchId = tnWhatsapp.BranchId,
                                        InstanceId = tnWhatsapp.InstanceId,
                                        Token = tnWhatsapp.Token,
                                        TenantName = tenant.CompanyName,
                                        DayLimit = tnWhatsapp.DayLimit,
                                        MinuteLimit = tnWhatsapp.MinuteLimit,
                                    })
                                    .ToListAsync();
```

But now I am not sure how to join another table, I want this `TnWhatsapp` table `BranchId` to join `TnBranch`table `Id`, then I want to get `TnBranch` table `Code`. Below is my edit part code inside the query, but it cannot work.

```html
var query = _saasdbContext.TnWhatsapp.AsNoTracking();

                if (isSAASAdmin == false)
                    query = query.Where(x => x.TenantId == tenantID);

                int totalCount = await query.CountAsync();
                query = QueryableExtensions.QueryOrderBy(query, sortList);
                List<TnWhatsappMessage> whatsappDedicatedListForTenant = new List<TnWhatsappMessage>();

                if (take == 0)
                    whatsappDedicatedListForTenant = await query.Skip(skip)
                                                    .Join(_saasdbContext.Tenant.AsNoTracking(),
                                                    tnWhatsapp => tnWhatsapp.TenantId,
                                                    tenant => tenant.Id,
                                                    (tnWhatsapp, tenant) => new { tnWhatsapp, tenant })
                                                    .Join(_saasdbContext.TnBranch.AsNoTracking(),
                                                    tnBranch => tnBranch.Id,
                                                    tnWhatsapp => tnWhatsapp.BranchId,
                                                    (tnWhatsapp, tenant, tnBranch) => new TnWhatsappMessage()
                                                    {
                                                        Id = tnWhatsapp.Id,
                                                        TenantId = tnWhatsapp.TenantId,
                                                        BranchId = tnWhatsapp.BranchId,
                                                        InstanceId = tnWhatsapp.InstanceId,
                                                        Token = tnWhatsapp.Token,
                                                        TenantName = tenant.CompanyName,
                                                        BranchName = tnBranch.Code,
                                                        DayLimit = tnWhatsapp.DayLimit,
                                                        MinuteLimit = tnWhatsapp.MinuteLimit,
                                                    })
                                                    .ToListAsync();
```

My error messages like the below picture:

[image]

This picture is my last try, but it also shows the errors.

[image: pic1]

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Use the LINQ Query syntax over the method syntax for a better readability. Also it will help you frame the queries better.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me a sample for reference according to my codes?

Comment: As I couldn't paste such a LONG code in this box, I have pasted here https://pastebin.com/1h7W8i16.

Comment: More details in here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Comment: @SathishGuruV You can click the "Answer Your Question" button answer, then if correct I can give you mark.

Comment: I have tried your code. It cannot be work.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/07/31/transparent-identifiers-part-one/

Comment: In the second join, as you wrote it, the final lambda has too many parameters. It only takes two.  The first parameter is the anonymous object (transparent identifier) that has `tnWhatsapp` and `tenant` properties as projected from the first join. The second parameter is the joined `tnBranch` range variable introduced in the second join.

Comment: @madreflection Agree. Do you have any solutions can modify based on my code?

Comment: Follow that link and read about transparent identifiers. When you use the extension methods directly, you don't get transparent identifiers so you have to manage those projections explicitly. That article will help you understand what you need to do.

Comment: Also, the code on pastebin doesn't work only because the identifiers are swapped in the `on` / `equals` part. Unlike SQL, the order matters. You should try it again and fix the order. LNQ query syntax is generally easier to read, especially for joins and other non-trivial expressions.

Comment: Thanks @madreflection, for the suggestion and I have corrected and added as an answer

Comment: I removed the linq-to-sql tag because this is Entity Framework. Please add a tag for the correct version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have enhanced the comment what I provided with the suggestion by @madreflection. Here is the Query syntax of your LINQ.

```
whatsappDedicatedListForTenant = await (
    from tnWhatsapp in query.Skip(skip)
    join tenant in _saasdbContext.Tenant.AsNoTracking() on tnWhatsapp.TenantId equals tenant.Id
    join tnBranch in _saasdbContext.TnBranch.AsNoTracking() on tnWhatsapp.BranchId equals tnBranch.Id
    select new TnWhatsappMessage()
    {
        Id = tnWhatsapp.Id,
        TenantId = tnWhatsapp.TenantId,
        BranchId = tnWhatsapp.BranchId,
        InstanceId = tnWhatsapp.InstanceId,
        Token = tnWhatsapp.Token,
        TenantName = tenant.CompanyName,
        BranchName = tnBranch.Code,
        DayLimit = tnWhatsapp.DayLimit,
        MinuteLimit = tnWhatsapp.MinuteLimit,
    }
).ToListAsync();
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT : Modified per the source of the OP.

Comment: Thanks. May I know how to use your code to modify my code there?

Comment: @FattSky I have made an edit to make the correction in line with your problem

Comment: Thanks. Let me check first

Comment: Still not working yet.

Comment: @FattSky Still throwing the exception when ran or no results?

Comment: Ok. I think solve it. Thank you

Comment: Can you help me look on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74443793/block-the-date-range-to-make-appointment-c if you know how to solve? Thank you @Sathish Guru