# Block the date range to make appointment (C#)

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a question about creating an appointment if matches the block date to check weekly in the hr organizer within the start date and stop date then cannot make an appointment. I am using **for each** to loop every week, to detect but cannot work.

**For the scenario sample (This is what I want the result):**

In the hr organizer, the admin set the user cannot create an appointment every Tuesday from 5 PM until Wednesday 12 PM, it will start from 22 Nov 2022 until 22 Dec 2022. Means that every week Tuesday from 5 PM until Wednesday 12 PM will block to create appointments until the end of 22 Dec 2022.

So now the user needs to create an appointment starting on 22 Nov 2022 at 5:40 PM and ending on 22 Nov 2022 at 6:40 PM. By right between this appointment time it won't let the user create the appointment because it has been blocked by the hr organizer. (**I am facing this problem the condition is not correct in my existing code.)

```html
formatAptStartDate= 22 Nov 2022 17:40 PM
aptEndDate = 22 Nov 2022 18:40 PM
formatStartDate = 22 Nov 2022 05:00 PM
formatEndDate = 23 Nov 2022 12:00:00 PM
stopLastDate = 22 Dec 2022 12:00 PM
```

**Existing sample code: (This code is not working meet what I mentioned in the above requirements)**

```html
if (repeatType == "Weekly")
{
    int weekDayNumberAptStartDate = (int)(formatAptStartDate.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7;
    int weekDayNumberStartDate = (int)(formatStartDate.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7;
    int weekDayNumberEndDate = (int)(formatEndDate.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7;
    if (weekDayNumberAptStartDate >= weekDayNumberStartDate && weekDayNumberAptStartDate <= weekDayNumberEndDate)
    {
        if (formatStopLastDate.Date >= formatAptStartDate.Date && formatStartDate.Date <= formatAptStartDate.Date)
        {
            for (DateTime dt = formatStartDate; dt <= stopLastDate; dt = dt.AddDays(7)) 
            {
                if (formatAptEndDate < dt || formatAptStartDate > formatEndDate)
                {
                    orgTimeSlot.IsAvailable = true;
                    orgTimeSlot.StartDate = null;
                    orgTimeSlot.StopDate = null;
                    continue;
                }   

                else
                {
                    orgTimeSlot.IsAvailable = false;
                    orgTimeSlot.StartDate = formatStartDate;
                    orgTimeSlot.StopDate = formatEndDate;
                    break;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

**Remark**

`orgTimeSlot.IsAvailable = true;` means that if not match the hr organizer block date, it will let the user create an appointment, else if `orgTimeSlot.IsAvailable = false;` means that the user cannot create an appointment.

Hope someone can guide or show me how to solve this problem and can meet the requirements.

Comment: The IF statement is wrong : if (formatAptEndDate < dt || formatAptStartDate > formatEndDate)

Comment: @jdweng Thank you comment. Do you know how to modify it?

Comment: I can't figure out the posted code.  It is missing variables formatStopLastDate and formatAptEndDate,  I understand what you are trying to do.  Makde sure dt is a valid date.  Also make sure the end date is really the end of a week and not middle of week.  I would test by add in for loop Console.WriteLine(dt); so you can make sure the code is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, do not try to do it the way you are trying to do. Instead create a collection of blocked datetimes and check user request overlaps with any of the blocks. ie:

```
void Main()
{
    var blockDateStart = new DateTime(2022, 11, 22);
    var blockDateEnd = new DateTime(2022, 12, 23); // until end of 11/22

    DayBlock[] blockWeekdays = {
        new DayBlock {DayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Tuesday, Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(17), End=TimeSpan.FromHours(24)},
        new DayBlock {DayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Wednesday, Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(0), End=TimeSpan.FromHours(12)},
    };

    var blocked = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(blockDateEnd - blockDateStart).TotalDays)
        .Select(e => new {Date=blockDateStart.AddDays(e)})
        .Where(e => blockWeekdays.Any(w => w.DayOfWeek == e.Date.DayOfWeek))
        .Select(e => new {
            From = e.Date.Add(blockWeekdays.Single(w => w.DayOfWeek == e.Date.DayOfWeek).Start),
            To = e.Date.Add(blockWeekdays.Single(w => w.DayOfWeek == e.Date.DayOfWeek).End)
        });

    var userApptStart = new DateTime(2022, 11, 22, 17, 40, 0);
    var userApptEnd = new DateTime(2022, 11, 22, 18, 40, 0);
    var isBlocked = blocked.Any(b => userApptEnd > b.From && userApptStart < b.To); 
    
    Console.WriteLine(isBlocked);
}

class DayBlock
{
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Start { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan End { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT If you want to get on which date\time its is blocked:

```
var blocking = blocked.Where(b => userApptEnd > b.From && userApptStart < b.To);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use if checks:

```
void Main()
{
    var blockDateStart = new DateTime(2022, 11, 22);
    var blockDateEnd = new DateTime(2022, 12, 23); // until end of 11/22

    DayBlock[] blockWeekdays = {
        new DayBlock {DayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Tuesday, Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(17), End=TimeSpan.FromHours(24)},
        new DayBlock {DayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Wednesday, Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(0), End=TimeSpan.FromHours(12)},
    };

    var userApptStart = new DateTime(2022, 11, 22, 17, 40, 0);
    var userApptEnd = new DateTime(2022, 11, 22, 18, 40, 0);
    
    
    var blocked = false;

    if (userApptEnd > blockDateStart && userApptStart < blockDateEnd)
    {
        var appTimeStart = userApptStart.TimeOfDay;
        var appTimeEnd = userApptEnd.TimeOfDay;
        var bmatch = blockWeekdays.SingleOrDefault(w => w.DayOfWeek == userApptStart.DayOfWeek &&
            appTimeEnd > w.Start && appTimeStart < w.End);

        if (bmatch != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Blocked by {userApptStart.Date.Add(bmatch.Start)}-{userApptStart.Date.Add(bmatch.End)} on {bmatch.DayOfWeek}");
            blocked = true;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(blocked);
}

class DayBlock
{
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Start { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan End { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me try first

Comment: Hi, May I know how to write if not hard coded. Because these come from what user select, because sometimes will choose Tuesday to Friday, Monday to Wednesday...


DayBlock[] blockWeekdays = {
                        new DayBlock {DayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Tuesday, Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(17), End=TimeSpan.FromHours(24)},
                        new DayBlock {DayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Wednesday, Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(0), End=TimeSpan.FromHours(12)},
                    };

Comment: How about if include minutes in the time span, for example 17:45 start to block

Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(17)

Comment: I think your concept should be ok, I just only confuse how to without hardcoded in the DayBlock [] weekdays and include hours and minutes in the time span.  Can you show me if not hardcoded code?

Comment: @FattSky, simply in a real world app you would keep those user choices in a database and DayBlock resembles the table structure for such block rules. It is hardcoded here just for sampling, imagine blockWeekDays as a Linq query.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it :

```
            DateTime formatAptStartDate = DateTime.Parse("22 Nov 2022 17:40 PM");
            DateTime aptEndDate = DateTime.Parse("22 Nov 2022 18:40 PM");
            DateTime formatStartDate = DateTime.Parse("22 Nov 2022 05:00 PM");
            DateTime formatEndDate = DateTime.Parse("23 Nov 2022 12:00:00 PM");
            DateTime stopLastDate = DateTime.Parse("22 Dec 2022 12:00 PM");

            DateTime sundayMidnight = formatAptStartDate.Date.AddDays(-1 * (int)formatAptStartDate.DayOfWeek);
            DateTime blockStartTime = sundayMidnight.AddDays((int)DayOfWeek.Tuesday).AddHours(17);
            DateTime blockEndTime = sundayMidnight.AddDays((int)DayOfWeek.Wednesday).AddHours(12);

            if ((aptEndDate <= blockStartTime) || (formatAptStartDate >= blockEndTime ))
            {
            }
```